# LWJGL: detecting left/right clicks when getButtonCount returns 0

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

On the Dell Inspiron 15 3000, the touchpad doesn't have any physical left/right buttons. Instead, it is one giant touchpad that is pressure sensitive. I'm assuming it detects right/left clicks based off of hand position on the trackpad.

In my LWJGL application, I detect mouse button clicks with `Mouse.isButtonDown(0)`. This works fine on computers with a mouse with physical buttons, but doesn't work on touchpads that lack physical buttons. `Mouse.getButtonCount()` returns **0**.

Has anybody had any success in detecting if a mouse button is pressed, should the user be using a trackpad that doesn't have physical buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who find this in the future, I did find a fix:

You cannot, should there be no physical buttons, use the `Mouse.isButtonDown()` method. Instead, you are going to have to read the event buffer. To do so, I wrote my own helper class:

```
public class Mouse{

    private static boolean button_left = false, button_right = false;

    public static boolean isButtonDown(int button){
        if(button == 0) return button_left;
        if(button == 1) return button_right;
        return false;
    }

    public static void update(){
        while(org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.next()){
                if(org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.getEventButton() == 0) button_left = org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.getEventButtonState();
            if(org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.getEventButton() == 1) button_right = org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.getEventButtonState();
        }
    }
}
```

The `update()` method is called every tick, and as such I can get button states using `Mouse.isButtonDown(button)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of using

```
org.lwjgl.input.Mouse
```

This class could be what you are searching for:

```
org.lwjgl.input.Controllers
```

http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Controllers.html

Im not entirely sure though since I only have a mouse and no way to test this with a touchpad.